# How to compute the 3D projection/transformation of an object based on a given homography matrix, so that the object can "stand" on that plane?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, augmented-reality, homography

Recently I have been studying Computer Vision, and just learned a bit about homography. Generally, a homography matrix describes a mapping from one plane to another.

[image: Basic Idea of Homography]

Is there a way to generalize the homography so that it can be applied to a 3d object?

If so, how do I **derive** such a transformation/projection matrix for the 3d objects using the homography matrix?

I am asking this because I am trying to make a 3D object keep "standing" on a plane no matter how we rotate the plane. Right now I used a tracker to track a flat rectangular surface and computed a homography to project an image to that surface. But I am not sure how I can do that for a 3D object.

[image: A rough idea of how the result can look like]

(The result should look a bit like this figure, except the 3d coordinate system will be replaced by a 3d object. )

Comment: homographies can only map planes to planes. pictures simply don't contain the information to look at parts of a 3D object that **aren't visible** in the picture. nothing can recover that information from a picture. talking about homographies here is kinda pointless. you aren't mapping planes to planes. -- your question is confusing. you seem to be asking how to do **Augmented Reality**, i.e. to draw a 3D object into a view, so it looks consistent with the scene. that requires **recovering the pose of an object** (that plane) from the scene. -- please focus your question and add research to it.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my question. I actually already have a 3D model represented by a voxel. I am not talking about the 3D reconstruction, but how to project a 3D object on a plane.
Recovering the pose of an object seems to be the right way, and I will look into it. But still, it would be nice if I can somehow link the knowledge of homography to this task for a better understanding of the concepts.
I am linking it to the homography because intuitively they seem to be relevant. For example, is it possible to compute a homography mapping the bottom plane of the object to the target?

Comment: a homography could be *decomposed* into rotation, translation, projection (camera), but that still leaves at least one degree of freedom. I believe there remain ambiguities or degrees of freedom in such a decomposition. just look at how AR is done typically. aruco is one implementation. there the pose of squares is recovered and given as rotation and translation (camera matrix fixed). that is what I mean by research. you'll find the details.